# What type should I use for a range (of array indices)?

Tags: c++, coding-style, range, std

I need to write some functions returning ranges within an array (you may, if you like, assume they're specified as starting position and length). I can't return a tuple, so I need to return some other type (and maybe it's a good idea anyway). Now, I'd like to return something that's both (somewhat) standard and does not incur a performance penalty due to vtables, convoluted ctors etc.

The options that come to mind are:

1. `std::pair<unsigned>` (or `std::pair<size_t>`).
2. a struct wrapping two `unsigned`s (or `size_t`'s).
3. Rolling my own Range class, sugar-coating it with utility methods.

I tried looking for a proper Range class, but couldn't find one. It's kind of strange that nothing in the standard library/STL uses a class for ranges.

Are there better alternatives? And if there aren't, which of the above would you recommend?

Comment: @ForEveR: Doesn't seem reasonable performance-wise. Plus, that adds another aspect of abstraction which is not necessary for use of this range. Some code might use it for iteration, other code might, say, `memcpy()` a part of an array.

Comment: @einpoklum bullshit. Recall that pointers are iterators. Assuming that iterators are not reasonable performance-wise pretty much amounts to hocus-pocus-driven programming.

Comment: @einpoklum, I have added a separate answer for "use a pair of iterators". Either way, using memcpy is not a good argument: Please consider using std::copy instead of memcpy in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why this is hard to answer is that it's not clear for what kinds of situations the range will be used. Even you probably don't know yet exactly.

In situations like this I recommend creating your own class, because that keeps you flexible. You can add member functions and nested typedefs as needed.

If in the end, when all use cases are clear and all member functions and auxiliary functions have been defined, it turns out that it could be replaced with a pair, then you can still replace the class with a `typedef`.

For the inner type I'd recommend iterators over integers, unless you want to store huge amounts of these ranges (in which case space optimization would be important and two integers (offset+length) would help save space).

Comment: Well, I want something generic (not as in 'templated') and general. Something you would pass as an argument to `string` or `vector` methods to obtain a contiguous substring or subvector (although, yes, I know they don't take ranges).

Comment: @einpoklum I don't understand. As you say, the functions of `std::` containers and algorithms don't take range arguments. Neither pairs nor anything else. They work with two separate iterator arguments. So to be able to call those, you'd have to write customized code in _any_ case.

Comment: I was just trying to emphasize the kind of generality I want. Something simple and general-purpose enough that it might *theoretically* go into the standard library - not something specific to my usage.

Comment: @einpoklum what you ask for does not seem general at all, given that you require indices. Something general which could theoretically end up in the standard library is [boost range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd write a separate class for the range. With no virtual calls there will be virtually no overhead for calling appropriate methods and you'll be free to define internal methods for range-specific operations, such as union, intersection, shift, clamp and so on.

Comment: But this comes up zillions of times for people! Surely we shouldn't all write our own individual Range classes...

Comment: As we do for various variations on list or other containers, for that matter. If you don't want to rewrite this class, simply put it in a toolbox library, write this class as reusable as possible and include it in your future projects such that you won't have to write it again later.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to write some functions returning ranges within an array (you may, if you like, assume they're specified as starting position and length).

That sounds like you need to group a pair of iterators.

> I can't return a tuple, so I need to return some other type (and maybe it's a good idea anyway).

Not sure why you cannot return a tuple, but you can try returning a pair of iterators, or (if you can't return a `std::pair`) creating your own struct around a pair of iterators.

> Now, I'd like to return something that's both (somewhat) standard and does not incur a performance penalty due to vtables, convoluted ctors etc.

A pair of iterators sounds good :)
(and I sound like a broken record)

> I tried looking for a proper Range class, but couldn't find one. It's kind of strange that nothing in the standard library/STL uses a class for ranges.

There is [boost::range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html), if you can use boost. You could roll your own if you're not allowed to use it. I would just use a pair of iterators ( :-> )

> [...] Are there better alternatives? And if there aren't, which of the above would you recommend?

Yes: use a pair of iterators: it's standard compatible, it's fast, it's idiomatic, it's not suffering from complex construction or vtables overhead and it's safe. It also follows the principle of least surprise.

Comment: But I want a specific type for a range, not a pair of (whatever). Are you suggesting that I define a range class via a pair of iterators? Also, iterators are essentially mutable (you can const them but that kind of defeats the purpose), and a range is essentially immutable.